# how can I show $H^1(g , Hom_C(g,M))=0$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

For a simple Lie algebra $g$ and a finite dimensional vector space $M$ with a trivial   $g-$action, how can I show $H^1(g , Hom_C(g,M))=0$?

Comment: Could you give some more context?  The question looks really odd to me at the moment - in particular, what hypotheses on $g$ are there? (in characteristic zero, the answer to a much more general question is just the Whitehead lemmas)

Comment: Just as a simple Lie algebra in characteristic zero, like as $sl_2(C)$.

Comment: Ok, but why $\hom(g,M)$ and M trivial? My point is that the Whitehead lemmas answer this question in much wider generality.

Comment: I think $Hom_C(g,M)$ is equal to $H^1(g,M)$ and by Whitehead lemma we have $H^1(g,M)=0$ and then we have the result?

Comment: No, think about what you wrote: it can't possibly be right because the hom space is not zero and you are claiming it is equal to something which is zero.

Comment: Can you give me some more hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given two $\mathfrak{g}$-modules $A$ and $B$, $M=Hom(A,B)$ is a  $\mathfrak{g}$-module via
$$
(x\cdot \phi)(a)=x.\phi(a)-\phi(x\cdot a),
$$
for $a\in A$, $x\in \mathfrak{g}$ and $\phi\in M$. By Whitehead's first lemma, $H^1(\mathfrak{g},M)=0$ for semisimple Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and for all finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{g}$-modules, in characteristic zero. In the above case, $A=\mathfrak{g}$ is the adjoint module. Note that
$$
H^1(\mathfrak{g},Hom(A,B))=Ext(A,B),
$$
the space of equivalence classes of module extensions of $A$ by $B$.